# Alamofire request perform after print out result

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, alamofire

I'm making an app about using APIs on website. It's a train timetable app. And I got in trouble in sending the data from one ViewController to another. The problem is why the global variable I created (trainNo) did not pass to another VC when code "self.trainNo.append(data2.intValue)"and"prepare(...)" is performed.
I use print statement to debug. I found that when button pressed, the print statement "print(self.trainNo)" out of Alamofire request statement is performed first, then "print(self.trainNo)" in Alamofire request performed. I don't know why it happens.

I tried using print statement in different place.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {


    APIUrl = "https://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/v2/Rail/TRA/DailyTimetable/OD/"+"\(startStationNo)"+"/to/"+"\(endStationNo)"+"/"+"\(selectedDate)"+"?$top=30&$format=JSON&$orderby=OriginStopTime/ArrivalTime"

    let request = setUpUrl(APIUrl: APIUrl)

    print("\(APIUrl)")

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
        do{
            let json: JSON = try JSON(data: response.data!)

            if let result = json.array {
                for data in result {

                    let data2 = data["DailyTrainInfo"]["TrainNo"]
                    self.trainNo.append(data2.intValue)
                    print(self.trainNo)

                }
            }
            else{
                print("ERROR in data2")
            }

        }
        catch{
            print("ERROR in json \(error)")
        }
    }
    print(self.trainNo)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is TimeTableController {
        let vc = segue.destination as? TimeTableController
        vc?.trainNo = self.trainNo
        print(self.trainNo)
    }
}
```

I expected that the value of trainNo will be changed and pass to another VC.
but it did't work.

actual result:

[]  //this one is "print(self.trainNo)" in button

[]  //this one is "print(self.trainNo)" in prepare

[101]
......
    [101, 3147, 371, 3157, 3167, 1] // these are "print(self.trainNo)"the loop in Alamofire

which means that the Alamofire request and loop perform after print statements, and I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Because the request is asynchronous , you need to use `self.performSegue(withIdentifier` inside the callback

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {


    APIUrl = "https://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/v2/Rail/TRA/DailyTimetable/OD/"+"\(startStationNo)"+"/to/"+"\(endStationNo)"+"/"+"\(selectedDate)"+"?$top=30&$format=JSON&$orderby=OriginStopTime/ArrivalTime"

    let request = setUpUrl(APIUrl: APIUrl)

    print("\(APIUrl)")

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
        do{
            let json: JSON = try JSON(data: response.data!)

            if let result = json.array {
                for data in result {

                    let data2 = data["DailyTrainInfo"]["TrainNo"]
                    self.trainNo.append(data2.intValue)
                    print(self.trainNo)

                }

                // this will trigger the segue
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueName", sender: nil)
            }
            else{
                print("ERROR in data2")
            }

        }
        catch{
            print("ERROR in json \(error)")
        }
    }
    print(self.trainNo)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is TimeTableController {
        let vc = segue.destination as? TimeTableController
        vc?.trainNo = self.trainNo
        print(self.trainNo)
    }
}
```

and connect the source of the segue to the vc itself not to the button , btw also you may need to show activity indicator before the request as a good UX , so user expects it's a network operation

Comment: thank you so much @Sh_Khan , it works. and i'll look into "asynchronous "~~